# Van der waals forces interaction

Tags: solid-state-physics, physical-chemistry, molecules

My slides say:

> A gas with low density in which you can consider the attractive energy the sum of the isolate atoms couple
>   $$
> u=\int^S_\sigma{4\pi\frac{N}{V}}\left(\frac{\beta}{r^6}\right)r^2\mathrm{d}r=-\frac{4\pi N\beta}{V}\int^S_\sigma{r^{-4}} \mathrm{d}r=-\frac{4\pi N\beta}{3V}\left(\frac{1}{s^3}-\frac{1}{\sigma^3}\right)
> $$

and then continue:

> $$
> =-\frac{4\pi N\beta}{3V{\sigma^3}}
> $$

where

- $\sigma$ is the diameter of the atom;
- $\frac{N}{V}$ is density.

**Question:** How was $\large{\frac{1}{s^3}}$ canceled to get from $\large{\frac{4\pi N\beta}{3V}\left(\frac{1}{s^3}-\frac{1}{\sigma^3}\right)}$ to ${\large{-\frac{4\pi N\beta}{3V{\sigma^3}}}}\,?$

Comment: Seems like a low-density gas would tend to have particles far apart, right?  If we take that to the limit, then $\lim\limits_{s \to \infty}{\left(\frac{1}{s^3}\right)} = \, ?$

Comment: Classic case of a bad slice. They should have said, that this is an approximation